# "Process functions" in iterative and recursive depth-first search

Tags: graphs, graph-traversal

I was reading *The Algorithm Design Manual* by Steven Skiena, and I noticed his use of "process functions" in depth-first search and breadth-first search. Consider the following pseudocode for depth-first search:

```
DFS(G,u)
    state[u] = "discovered"
    process_vertex_early(u)
    entry[u] = time
    time = time + 1
    for every vertex v adjacent to u
        if state[v] = "undiscovered"
            parent[v] = u
            process_edge(u,v)
            DFS(G,v)
        else if state[v] != "processed" or G is directed
            process_edge(u,v)
    state[u] = "processed"
    exit[u] = time
    process_vertex_late(u)
    time = time + 1
```

Notice the use of the `process_vertex_early`, `process_edge`, and `process_vertex_late` functions.

I am attempting to implement an iterative version of depth-first search to avoid a stack overflow with larger graphs. Here is the pseudocode for my attempt:

```
DFS(G)
    mark every vertex in G as "undiscovered"
    mark the start and finish time for every vertex in G as (0, 0)
    time = 0
    for every vertex vrtx in G
        create empty stack S
        if vrtx is "undiscovered"
            S.push(vrtx)
        while S is not empty
            time = time + 1
            u = S.top
            if u is "undiscovered"
                u.start_time = time
                mark u as "discovered"
                process_vertex_early(u)
            done = true
            for every vertex v adjacent to u
                if v is "undiscovered"
                    done = false
                    v.parent = u
                    process_edge(u,v)
                    S.push(v)
                else if v is not "processed" or G is directed
                    process_edge(u,v)
            if done
                S.pop
                mark u as "processed"
                u.finish_time = time
                process_vertex_late(orig)
```

I ran both versions of the code for a sample graph of 10 vertices and generated the following data:

```
Iterative data:
vertex  early   edge    late    s_time  f_time  parent
0       1       1       1       1       18      -1
1       1       1       1       14      14      5
2       1       1       1       13      13      5
3       1       3       1       5       11      7
4       1       3       1       2       17      0
5       1       6       1       3       16      4
6       1       3       1       6       10      3
7       1       3       1       4       12      5
8       1       3       2       8       8       9
9       1       3       1       7       9       6


Recursive data:
vertex  early   edge    late    s_time  f_time  parent
0       1       1       1       1       20      -1
1       1       1       1       14      15      5
2       1       1       1       16      17      5
3       1       2       1       7       10      6
4       1       2       1       2       19      0
5       1       4       1       3       18      4
6       1       2       1       6       11      9
7       1       2       1       8       9       3
8       1       2       1       4       13      5
9       1       2       1       5       12      8
```

Here is the adjacency list for the graph I used:

```
0 : 4
1 : 5
2 : 5
3 : 6,7
4 : 0,5
5 : 1,2,4,7,8
6 : 3,9
7 : 3,5
8 : 5,9
9 : 6,8
```

I know that the vertices will be visited in different orders for the recursive and iterative implementations and that neither order is right or wrong, which is why the values for s_time, f_time and parent are different. The `early` and `late` columns represent the number of times each function was called for each vertex, while the `edge` column represents the number of times the `process_edge` function was called for each vertex as the `u` vertex. I feel like these values should be the same for both implementations or at least more similar than they are.

My question is: have I preserved the semantics of the original algorithm with my iterative translation? What changes, if any, should I make?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an iterative algorithm which preserves the behavior of the original recursive algorithm. The idea is to let each vertex to keep track of its next child to visit.

```
Iterative DFS on G starting at vertex v
    mark every vertex in G as "undiscovered"
    create stack S, each of whose elements will be a pair that consists of a vertex and the index of its next child to visit
    S.push([v,0])
    state[v] = "discovered"
    process_vertex_early(v)

    while S is not empty
        let [v, i] be the top element of S
        if i is less than the number of neighbours of v
            update that element to [v, i+1]
            let w be the i-th neighbour of v
            if w is marked "undiscovered"
                state[w] = "discovered"
                process_vertex_early(w)
                parent[w] = v
                S.push([w, 0])
                process_edge(v, w)
            else if state[w] is not "processed" or G is directed
                process_edge(v,w)
        else
            pop S
            process_vertex_late(v)
            state[v] = "processed"
```

There are general strategies that convert recursive algorithm/functions to iterative algorithm/functions. You can search "recursion and iteration" for more information if you have not done it yet.

Answer (score 1):

I accepted [the answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/102145/86461) by @Apass.Jack because it did allow me to exactly replicate the behavior of the original algorithm, albeit with some modifications. I wanted to get the start and finish times for each vertex, so I modified it to get those. I also modified it so that it does not allow the user to provide a start vertex and instead iterates through all the vertices, as in CLRS. I had forgotten to mention this when I asked the question.

**Updated pseudocode**:

```
DFS(G)
    mark every vertex in G as "undiscovered"
    set the start and finish time for every vertex in G to (0,0)
    set the parent for every vertex in G to -1
    time = 0
    for every vertex u in G
        create stack S, each of whose elements will be a pair that consists of a vertex and the index of its next child to visit
        if u is "undiscovered"
            S.push([u,0])
        while S is not empty
            let [v,i] be the top element of S
            if v is "undiscovered"
                time = time + 1
                v.start_time = time
                mark v as "discovered"
                process_vertex_early(v)
            if i is less than the number of neighbors of v
                update that element to [v,i+1]
                let w be the i-th neighbour of v
                if w is marked "undiscovered"
                    parent[w] = v
                    process_edge(v,w)
                    S.push([w,0])
                else if state[w] is not "processed" or G is directed
                    process_edge(v,w)
            else
                time = time + 1
                pop S
                state[v] = "processed"
                process_vertex_late(v)
                v.finish_time = time
```

This new algorithm generates the same exact data as the recursive pseudocode presented in the original question, both for directed and undirected graphs.